# When do daily quests appear and expire?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Every day, Heroes of the Storm grants you a new daily quest with a gold reward, i.e. "play 2 games as an Assassin Hero", "play 3 games as a Warcraft hero", and so on.

I currently have more than one of these "daily" quests active, so how exactly do they work? When do I get new dailies, and how long do I have to complete them before they disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you reach player level 6, Daily Quests will start to appear at 2 AM PST (10 AM UTC) on North American servers.  This time is not adjusted for daylight savings, so if you live in an area under daylight savings, then quests will appear an hour later.

You can retain up to three Daily Quests at one time.  Unlike Hearthstone, you cannot abandon a quest.  They persist until you complete them.

The [possible Daily Quests](http://heroesofthestorm.wikia.com/wiki/Daily_Quest) are currently:

- Play 8 Games (Any Mode) - 800 gold
- Win 3 Games (Any Mode) - 600 gold
- Play 3 Games as an Assassin Hero - 300 gold
- Play 3 Games as a Warrior Hero - 300 gold
- Play 3 Games as a Support Hero - 300 gold
- Play 3 Games as a Specialist Hero - 300 gold
- Play 2 Games As a Warcraft Hero - 200 gold
- Play 2 Games As a Diablo Hero - 200 gold
- Play 2 Games As a StarCraft Hero - 200 gold

Answer (score 7):

I believe Daily Quests roll over at Midnight PST (Blizzard time).

That said, quests work exactly like they do in Hearthstone, namely:

- You can have up to 3 of them at a time
- They last until completed, or canceled (press the X on your profile).

Answer (score 6):

> - I currently have more than one of these "daily" quests active, so how exactly do they work?
> - ... and how long do I have to complete them before they disappear?

Daily quests will not disappear until you complete them and they work similar to the Hearthstone daily quests except for one point: unlike Hearthstone dailies, you cannot reroll a quest in Heroes.

> - When do I get new dailies?

On EU servers at 3:00 AM (UTC), you will get new quests. Even if you started a game before 3:00 AM and completed the game after 3:00 AM, if your hero qualifies for the new daily quest, your game counts towards the daily.